# TypeScript interfaces and constructors

Tags: javascript, typescript

My constructor can't see method in interface and i have such a problem:
Class 'Board' incorrectly implements interface 'IBoard'.
Property 'makeBoard' is missing in type 'Board' but required in type 'IBoard'.

How to handle it?

```ts
interface ICell {
    x: number,
    y: number,
    showBoard(): void,
    ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D
}

export interface IBoard {
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
  cell: Array<ICell>;
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
  createCell(x:number, y:number, ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D, color:string): void,
  createCells(): void,
  showBoard(): void,
  makeBoard(): void
}

export class Board implements IBoard {
  cell: Array<ICell> = [];
  canvas = document.getElementById('chessBoard-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  
  constructor() {
    this.makeBoard();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the function makeBoard in Board class. Interface is just a contract. It basically says: If you have class that implements this interface it must have methods, that you declared in the interface.

Add make board method to Board class.

```
 makeBoard(): void {
  throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the methods that the interface describes. You've written that an `IBoard` needs the `createCell`, `createCells`, `showBoard`, and `makeBoard` methods, yet you haven't written those methods on the `Board` class.

This should get rid of the error, but I'd recommend filling out the functions:

```ts
export class Board implements IBoard {
  cell: Array<ICell> = [];
  canvas = document.getElementById('chessBoard-canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  constructor() {
    this.makeBoard();
  }

  createCell(x,y,ctx,color) {
    return;
  }
  createCells() {
    return;
  }
  showBoard() {
    return;
  }
  makeBoard() {
    return;
  }
}
```